# Filtering ansible output

Tags: json, ansible, filtering

I'm trying to filter a list of attributes from the below output. selection and value attributes need to be listed.
Output:

```
    ok: [192.0.0.3] => {
        "allow": "GET, PUT", 
        "attempts": 1, 
        "invocation": {
            }
        }, 
        "json": {
            "body": [
                {
                    "selection": "fqdn", 
                    "value": "airbus3.org"
                }, 
                {
                   "selection": "fqdn", 
                   "value": "airbus4.org"
                }
            ], 
            "key": "ntp_servers", 
            "meta": {
                "transaction": "/api/transaction"
            }
       }, 
    }
```

I'm trying to use the below task to filter but it's not working.

```
    - set_fact:
        ntp_details: "{{ item.selection }}"
      with_items: "{{ reg_ntp.json.body | json_query('[*]') }}"
```

Please advise..

Comment: The braces are not balanced. Make sure it's [valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/) especially when you edit it manually.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ntp_details: "{{ reg_ntp.json.body|json_query('[].selection') }}"
```

should give

```
  ntp_details:
  - fqdn
  - fqdn
```